# Evaluate the double integral with sin/cos

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis, multivariable-calculus

> $$\iint_\limits{D}\sin(x)\cos(y) dA$$ where $A$ is bounded by $y = 1 + x, y = 1 - x, y = 0$.

So this is obviously a triangle region, lets split it into 2 region such that $D_1 + D_2 = D$.

Lets calculate: $\iint_\limits{D_1}\sin(x)\cos(y) dA$ first.

If I fix $y$ from say $0 \to 1$, then I get $x_{\text{left}} = -1$ and $x_{\text{right}} = 0$.

So I should get

$$\iint_\limits{D_1}\sin(x)\cos(y) dA = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{-1}^{0} \sin(x)\cos(y) dx dy = \sin(1) \cdot (\cos(1)  -1)$$

But this isnt right. How do I make sure I am getting the right limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You let $y$ go from $0$ to $1$.  When $y$ is at some value, say $y=1/2$, then the range for $x$ is not $-1$ to $0$.  The left bound is the line $y=1+x$ and when $y=1/2,$ the left limit for $x$ is $-1/2$.  And it's different for every value of $y$.  So the $x$ limits can't be $-1$ to $0$.  They have to depend on $y$.

In general, as $y$ goes from $a$ to $b$, then $x$ goes from "left-function of $y$" to "right function of $y$".   (Or as $x$ goes from $a$ to $b$, then $y$ goes from "bottom function of $x$" to "top function of $x$.")  A region that can't be expresses in one of these two ways needs to be cut into regions which can be.

Comment: Thanks, I needed the logic behind it

Answer (score 1):

How about  $\int_0^1\int_{y-1}^{1-y}\sin (x)\cos (y)dxdy $.  We get  $\int_0^1\cos (y)(-\cos (1-y)+\cos (y-1))dy =O $ because  $\cos  (x) $ is an even function.

Comment: Type \sin x, \cos x, \tan x, \csc x, \sec x, and \cot x, respectively, when you are in math mode to obtain $\sin x$, $\cos x$, $\tan x$, $\csc x$, $\sec x$, and $\cot x$.

Comment: But why doesnt my approach work?

Comment: Why are the limits from y -1 to 1 - y instead of -1 to 0??

Comment: You integrated over a rectangle.   You need variables in the limits of your first integral. ..

Comment: I solved for $x$ in terms of  $y$.  You could do it the other way :  $(x-1)$ to $(x+1)$, and $-1$ to $1$...